# Buttons won't go side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the menu button and search button to sit side by side in the header, but nothing seems to be working. Below is an image of what I'm currently getting as well as the relevant markup and style for the buttons.

What I'm getting: 
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" id="searchbuttonmobile" ><img src="~/Images/SearchBtn.png" /></button>                        
                        <button type="button" onclick="openNav()" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mobilenav" id="menubutton">
                            <img src="~/Images/MobileMenuBtn.png" />
                        </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*----------------------------------*/
/*---MOBILE MENU LOGO AND BUTTONS---*/
/*----------------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 400px) {

    #logo {
        width: 100px;
    }

    #smokefree {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

        #smokefree a {
            font-size: 14pt;
        }



    #menubutton img {
        width: 43px;
        height: 44px;
    }

    #searchbuttonmobile {
        padding: 9px 0px;
    }

    #searchbuttonmobile img {
        width: 43px;
        height: 44px;
    }
}


/*--------------------------------------*/
/*--------MENU BUTTON APPEARANCE--------*/
/*--------------------------------------*/
@media (max-width: 1279px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }

    .navbar-left, .navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }

    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.collapse, .desktopnav {
        display: none !important;
    }

    #mobilenav {
        display: block;
    }

    #searchbuttonmobile {
        padding: 9px 10px;
        display: inline;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        float: none !important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }

        .navbar-nav > li {
            float: none;
        }

            .navbar-nav > li > a {
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }

    .collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: buttons have are by default, block elements (as in display: block;) what you wanna do is add `display: inline-block` to your button css :)

Comment: can't reproduce, the code you posted is not enought

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Tried that, they still stay stacked. :-(

Comment: @M.Straw you want something like this? use `float: right;`: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/sgy5jo81/

Comment: @M.Straw huh - odd, must be some other force of nature at work :) try float suggested by AMH :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change button display to inline-block as ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs written on comment. 
also you can float buttons to right.

```
.navbar-header button{
float:right;
display:block;
}
```

or use:

```
.navbar-header button{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Floating the buttons after doing what @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs suggested worked. Really simple, thanks you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Change `display: block` to `display: inline-block` in `.navbar-toggle`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-header button{
      float:right;
    }
```

Add the above code in your CSS.

Here is Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bebgt8av/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only `float:right;` could make it work.

Follow this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suketupatel116/pkqndggu/) link.